# Errors trying to flatten a response object from Google's Entity Sentiment Analysis in Python

Tags: python, pandas, flatten

**Goal**

I'm trying to flatten a response object from google's entity sentiment analysis that's in a field named `entitysentiment` in a pandas dataframe (`df`) in a python notebook. A sample of one of the response object entries for a single row's `entitysentiment` field is below[1].

It needs to loop through each row of the df, find the `entitysentiment` field, and flatten the object and its nested objects.

The latest function I've tried is below[2]. And the resulting error message is [3].

In [2], my previously attempted version is commented out, but it received the error message `AttributeError: Unknown field for AnalyzeEntitySentimentResponse: split`.

Any input on how to approach this or thoughts on what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

[1]
`entities {\n  name: "login page"\n  type_: OTHER\n  salience: 0.5467509031295776\n  mentions {\n    text {\n      content: "login page"\n      begin_offset: 24\n    }\n    type_: COMMON\n    sentiment {\n      magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n      score: -0.4000000059604645\n    }\n  }\n  sentiment {\n    magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n    score: -0.4000000059604645\n  }\n}\nentities {\n  name: "app"\n  type_: CONSUMER_GOOD\n  salience: 0.45324909687042236\n  mentions {\n    text {\n      content: "app"\n      begin_offset: 52\n    }\n    type_: COMMON\n    sentiment {\n      magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n      score: -0.4000000059604645\n    }\n  }\n  sentiment {\n    magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n    score: -0.4000000059604645\n  }\n}\nlanguage: "en"\n`

[2]

```
"""
# Define a function to extract entity mentions from entitysentiment
def extract_entities(text):
    entities = []
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        if 'content:' in line:
            entity = line.strip().split(':')[-1].strip().replace("'", "")
            entities.append(entity)
    return entities
"""

def extract_entities(text):
    entities = []
    if 'entity_mentions' not in text:
        return entities
    for entity in text['entity_mentions']:
        entities.append(entity['content'])
    return entities



# Apply the function to the entitysentiment column
df['entity_mentions'] = df['entitysentiment'].apply(extract_entities)

# Convert the entity mentions to separate columns
entity_mentions_df = pd.DataFrame(df['entity_mentions'].to_list(), columns=['entity_mention_1', 'entity_mention_2', 'entity_mention_3'])

# Concatenate the original dataframe with the entity mentions dataframe
result = pd.concat([df, entity_mentions_df], axis=1)

# Drop the original entitysentiment and entity_mentions columns
result.drop(['entitysentiment', 'entity_mentions'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Show the result
print(result)
```

[3]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1/3330714854.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # Apply the function to the entitysentiment column
---> 24 df['entity_mentions'] = df['entitysentiment'].apply(extract_entities)
     25 
     26 # Convert the entity mentions to separate columns

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4355         dtype: float64
   4356         """
-> 4357         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4358 
   4359     def _reduce(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply(self)
   1041             return self.apply_str()
   1042 
-> 1043         return self.apply_standard()
   1044 
   1045     def agg(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1099                     values,
   1100                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
-> 1101                     convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1102                 )
   1103 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/tmp/ipykernel_1/3330714854.py in extract_entities(text)
     13 def extract_entities(text):
     14     entities = []
---> 15     if 'entity_mentions' not in text:
     16         return entities
     17     for entity in text['entity_mentions']:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/proto/message.py in __contains__(self, key)
    686                 wire serialization.
    687         """
--> 688         pb_value = getattr(self._pb, key)
    689         try:
    690             # Protocol buffers "HasField" is unfriendly; it only works

AttributeError: entity_mentions
```

Answer (score 0):

With the text string you provided:

```py
obj = 'entities {\n  name: "login page"\n  type_: OTHER\n  salience: 0.5467509031295776\n  mentions {\n    text {\n      content: "login page"\n      begin_offset: 24\n    }\n    type_: COMMON\n    sentiment {\n      magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n      score: -0.4000000059604645\n    }\n  }\n  sentiment {\n    magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n    score: -0.4000000059604645\n  }\n}\nentities {\n  name: "app"\n  type_: CONSUMER_GOOD\n  salience: 0.45324909687042236\n  mentions {\n    text {\n      content: "app"\n      begin_offset: 52\n    }\n    type_: COMMON\n    sentiment {\n      magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n      score: -0.4000000059604645\n    }\n  }\n  sentiment {\n    magnitude: 0.4000000059604645\n    score: -0.4000000059604645\n  }\n}\nlanguage: "en"\n'
```

```py
print(obj)
# Output

entities {
  name: "login page"
  type_: OTHER
  salience: 0.5467509031295776
  mentions {
    text {
      content: "login page"
      begin_offset: 24
    }
    type_: COMMON
    sentiment {
      magnitude: 0.4000000059604645
      score: -0.4000000059604645
    }
  }
  sentiment {
    magnitude: 0.4000000059604645
    score: -0.4000000059604645
  }
}
entities {
  name: "app"
  type_: CONSUMER_GOOD
  salience: 0.45324909687042236
  mentions {
    text {
      content: "app"
      begin_offset: 52
    }
    type_: COMMON
    sentiment {
      magnitude: 0.4000000059604645
      score: -0.4000000059604645
    }
  }
  sentiment {
    magnitude: 0.4000000059604645
    score: -0.4000000059604645
  }
}
language: "en"
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Save "language" info for last step
language = (
    [item for item in obj.split("}\n}\n") if item.startswith("language")][0]
    .replace('"', "")
    .replace("\n", "")
)
language = {language.split(": ")[0]: language.split(": ")[1]}

# Split on "entities" and cleanup
new_items = [
    [
        sub_item.replace(" {", "")
        .replace("    ", "")
        .replace("  ", "")
        .replace("\n", "")
        .replace("}}", "")
        .replace('"', "")
        for sub_item in item.split("\n  ")
        if not sub_item in (" {", "  }", "}")
    ]
    for item in obj.split("entities")
    if item
]

# Split on ": "
new_items = [
    [new_sub_item for new_sub_item in new_item if ": " in new_sub_item]
    for new_item in new_items
]

# Deal with duplicated "type_:"
for new_item in new_items:
    j = 0
    for i, new_sub_item in enumerate(new_item):
        if "type_:" in new_sub_item:
            new_item[i] = new_sub_item.replace("type_:", f"type_{j}:")
            j += 1

# Make final list of dictionaries with appropriate keys an values
new_items = [
    {
        new_sub_item.split(": ")[0]: new_sub_item.split(": ")[1]
        for new_sub_item in new_item
    }
    | language
    for new_item in new_items
]
```

Then:

```py
[{'begin_offset': '24',
  'content': 'login page',
  'language': 'en',
  'magnitude': '0.4000000059604645',
  'name': 'login page',
  'salience': '0.5467509031295776',
  'score': '-0.4000000059604645',
  'type_0': 'OTHER',
  'type_1': 'COMMON'},
 {'begin_offset': '52',
  'content': 'app',
  'language': 'en',
  'magnitude': '0.4000000059604645',
  'name': 'app',
  'salience': '0.45324909687042236',
  'score': '-0.4000000059604645',
  'type_0': 'CONSUMER_GOOD',
  'type_1': 'COMMON'}]
```

Comment: Thx @Laurent, appreciate the input. I tried loading your `obj` but got this error: `  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1/60143271.py", line 6
    entities {
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` \\ the invalid syntax carrot pointing to the 'entities' object

Comment: Hi, are you sure you copied the (long) line entirely (and not the output of print(obj))? When I do, I don't get any syntax error and the code works fines. Cheers.